# How to add the same animation node tree to multiple meshes (meshes need to have different image textures)

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders

In short, I have a plane, with an image texture on it, which will act as a flower.

My question is, since I need 21 different flowers, can I duplicate that first plane (flower), on which I already have set up a node tree, so that the duplicated one shares the same node tree but has different image (texture)? That would mean also for the next 20 planes (textures)?

Or do I need to keep adding plane by plane, applying textures on each one of them, and for each have 21 node trees (that are basically the same).

Just for the records, if it means anything for this process, I intend to group those flowers in one group, which would act as particle emitter, so that I end up with an animation of falling flowers (i would set one big plane as emmiter of particles, which i would ofcourse link them to the group, which would made the particles to be the actual flowers, that would fall randomly...)

Please, anyone knows if I can duplicate that way, and how? It would simply save me a lot of time.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you show your current nodetree and the implementation of the texture in the shader? I'm not sure what's the part that involves "animation". Did you already considered to use Node Groups for this taks? Here's a possibly related question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91354/single-a-single-material-across-several-objects-with-individual-control

Comment: Hello, and thanks for commenting! I dont think the link you sent me is the case. Well, i am not at this moment anywhere near my working station, so i cant really remember exactly every node setup, but basically, i have a plane on which there is a texture uv mapped on, (texture is flower), so that plane simply acts as a set up for my flower(s), and has a node tree with some nodes effecting it to make it spicy, usuall stuff. But since needed 20 more planes (flowers), with the same node effects( its just that i need texture variations), i went on and copy/paste node tree on second plane and so on

Comment: So you see its a long way around....and later i had those 21 planes(flowers), removed on each witb nodes the plane visibility so i only end up with the flower (texture) as i need the to be falling in animation, simple as that. I group all those planes, and appliead a particle effect on a group, and thats that (another big plane acting as a emitter). Its just that i dont know how to, through all those planes, i have the same node tree effect, except i only needed texture to be different( same planes)

Comment: The whole "node tree with some nodes effecting it to make it spicy" part can be Gruoped as shown in the linked question. You'll then just have to set up a different input texture for each material, as the other part is shared acoross all the materials. Is this a path you already followed or you tried but didn't worked?

Comment: No. I did it with copying the node tree from the first object, and then making instances of the same 21 times more, and then ctrl+v in the node tree of others. Then, i would just change the texture in those individual objects (node trees) and add different one. Longer way?

Comment: In my opinion, it's a fine way to approach the task. If you need to add more flower types, you just have to duplicate the material and change the texture. If you prefer to use one material only, you can put all the texture togheter and control the mixing with a mask (e.g. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93700/node-editor-pick-random-image-texture-from-set). For some project, maybe it would be better to create a texture atlas and play with the UV shifting. If you have hudreds of texture to pick from, maybe it worth scripting some code to access them...

Comment: As the presented situation is looking for peculiar control of a limited number of textures, I would go for the solution presented in the previously linked question.

Comment: I do see your point. Thanks for the feedback a lot :)!